# MvvmCross 6.0: How to pass parameter to App on initialization?

Tags: c#, xamarin, initialization, mvvmcross

after the update to MvvmCross 6.1.2 my code is telling me that the App-class has to have a parameterless constructor. The problem is that until now I passed the filepath to the database to the App using it's constructor.

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MyDatabase.db");
return new App(dbPath);
```

There should be a way to do this, yet I haven't found information on it for MvvmCross 6.0. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1:**

Instead of passing database path into App constructor, you can get this path into Core, using `Mvx` registration.

```
public interface IDBPathService
{
    string GetDBPath();
}


public class  DBPathService : IDBPathService
{

    public string GetDBPath()
    {
         return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MyDatabase.db");
    }
}
```

In `App.cs` class there would be `Initailize` method which should be registering this implementation using

```
CreatableTypes() 
    .EndingWith("Service")
    .AsInterfaces()
    .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

Now you can get path using

```
var dbpath = Mvx.Resolve<IDBPathService>().GetDBPath();
```

**Way 2:**

Another simpler way is taking static property into your `App.cs` class and assign path directly from Native projects like.

In `App.cs` class define a static property:

```
public static string DBPath;
```

In Platform specific projects assign path like:

```
App.DBPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MyDatabase.db");
```

Comment: Thanks, used the static property way :)